# Как сделать вдавленный эффект для стрелок prev/next?

Tags: css3, slider, owl-carousel

[image]

Как сделать вдавленный эффект стрелочкам (cтрелочки в SVG)?

Comment: Похоже на тень. Что в самих svg?

Comment: Что стили? Какой вопрос?

Comment: первое что приходит в голову box-shadow

Answer (score 1):

Есть идея! Лично я сделал бы так, двойной фон:

1. Делаем стрелочки как "белый кружок **с вырезанной** стрелкой. То есть круглая белая таблетка, а посредине - кривая прозрачная область.
2. Затем кнопке назначаем первый фон, это бело-серый радиальный градиент, поверх него через запятую кладем второй фон - иконку с прозрачной стрелкой.

**Итого**, поигравшись со сдвигом и размером градиента имеем серый неравномерный фон внутри прозрачной стрелки.

Или реализовать тени полностью а редакторе в свг и приложить единой фоновой картинкой.